# Как извлечь временную составляющую из DateTime?

Tags: c#

При выводе на консоль объекта типа `DateTime` выводится и дата и время.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

> ```
> 10/19/2016 7:25:40 PM
> ```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы выводилось только время?

Comment: вам [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397500(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Alex.B Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть два способа. С помощью [форматов](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm), в строку:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string time_str = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

С помощью [свойства `TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) в `TimeSpan`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = dt.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы получить текущее время в виде строки, [используйте](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#LongTime)

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
```

Вывести строку на экран, надеюсь, сможете самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3):

Вот еще один вариант:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

Comment: ...или `ToLongTimeString()`.